# Trouble translating Mac network GUI to Windows one

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, language

I am an international student in France and in my dormitory there's a manual how to have access to Wi-Fi though it's in French and directed to macOS users. I have bought an Ethernet cable and connected it to the plug-in yet can't follow the instructions. Could someone guide me through it if he's a French speaker or at least provide some technical support ? I know this isn't exactly what SuperUser was made for but it's a technical issue with Ethernet connection.

[Instructions to be followed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cwpR.jpg)

Comment: Can't you ask your college IT team for help? They should have a guide for Windows as well.

Comment: Or ask the students next door (good opportunity to get to know them). Basically you have to obtain your MAC address and then do some stuff with it, it's easy to google how to do that on Windows.